# IntelliJ "Unused variable" Angular

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm

As I am learning @ngrx I realized the following:

When I define an Observable as a component attribute and suffix it with `$`, and only use it in the template .html-file, IntelliJ does not register the attribute as used but displays it grey. This *only* happens when the variable ends with `$`.. Any idea how that is possible?

[image: Inside the component]
[image: In the component's template]

Comment: Maybe they have a bug related to that :) Don't see other explanation. The $ is just a part of the name, so if it works without it I would expect to work with it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue, tracked as [WEB-34352](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34352). 
Renaming your variable to a name without `$` suffix should help